# How to include NULL values in a query with Outer Join and Group By

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables with the following sample data:

```
Table 1: `item_name`
| item_id | item_desc |
| 1       | apple     |
| 2       | orange    |
| 3       | banana    |
| 4       | grape     |
| 5       | mango     |

Table 2: `user_items`
| user_id | item_id |
| 127     | 1       |
| 127     | 2       |
| 127     | 4       |
| 128     | 1       |
| 128     | 5       |
```

I'm trying to select a total of each item_id both user_id 127 and 128 have, along with the corresponding item_desc using the following query:

```
SELECT IFNULL(COUNT(ui.user_id), 0) AS total, in.item_desc 
FROM user_items AS ui 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN item_name AS in 
    ON ui.item_id = in.item_id 
WHERE ui.user_id IN (127, 128) 
GROUP BY ui.item_id
ORDER BY total DESC
```

The result of the above query is:

```
| total | item_desc |
| 2     | apple     |
| 1     | orange    |
| 1     | grape     |
| 1     | mango     |
```

but it didn't include item_id 3, banana, which I wanted to retrieve with RIGHT OUTER JOIN. I was hoping to get a result that looked like this:

```
| total | item_desc |
| 2     | apple     |
| 1     | orange    |
| 1     | grape     |
| 1     | mango     |
| 0     | banana    |
```

Is there any way to modify the query to end up with the intended result above?
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 6):

There was a little error in your query using count. This works.

```
select count(ui.item_id) as total, in.item_desc
from   item_name `in`
       left join user_items ui on ui.item_id = in.item_id
                                        and ui.user_id in (127, 128)
group by
       in.item_desc
order by total desc
```

Comment: I don't see the error? afaik, `COUNT(*)` is valid SQL with any `GROUP BY` arrangement (at least in SQL Server).

Comment: If you test your query you will see that you'll have banana 1. ;)

Answer (score 4):

Your `WHERE` clause as it is is essentially removing all records from `item_name` that don't relate to `user_id`'s 127 & 128.

In order to fix that, the easiest solution would be to `LEFT JOIN` from the `item_name` table to the `user_items` table and apply the selection of `user_id`'s on the `JOIN`.

```
SELECT COUNT(*), itn.item_desc
FROM   item_name AS itn
       LEFT OUTER JOIN user_items AS ui ON ui.item_id = itn.item_id
                                           AND ui.user_id IN (127, 128)
GROUP BY
       itn.item_desc
```

*note that while this can be written as a `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`, I find that type of joins to be counterintuïtive and would advise on only using them when absolutely necessary.*