# MYSQL select number of elements FOREACH element in another table

Tags: mysql, select, foreach, count, nested

I have two databases, each containing one table,  users.user_groups and logins.logins.

The first one contains a list of users and their corresponding groups as follows :-

mysql>select * from users.user_groups;

> +----------+-------------------+
>   | username | group_type   |
>   +----------+-------------------+
>   | user_1   | group_1     |
>   | user_2   | group_1 |
>   | user_3   | group_1 |
>   | user_4   | group_2 |
>   | user_5   | group_2 |
>   | user_6   | group_2 |
>   | user_7   | group_3 |
>   | user_8   | group_3 |
>   | user_9   | group_3 |
>   +----------+---------+

so user_1, user_2, user_3 form part of group_1, user_4, user_5, user_6 form part of group_2 etc.

Table logins, inside database logins contains a track record of when the users log in the system :-

select * from logins.logins;

> +-----------+---------------------+
>   | user_name | login_date          |
>   +-----------+---------------------+
>   | user_1    | 2014-06-01 09:11:09 |
>   | user_1    | 2014-06-02 02:11:09 |
>   | user_2    | 2014-06-08 02:13:43 |
>   | user_1    | 2014-06-02 03:13:42 |
>   | user_3    | 2014-06-02 03:13:42 |
>   | user_2    | 2014-06-02 03:13:42 |
>   | user_1    | 2014-06-08 03:13:42 |
>   | user_4    | 2014-06-02 03:13:42 |
>   | user_5    | 2014-06-02 03:13:42 |
>   | user_8    | 2014-06-02 03:13:42 |
>   | user_9    | 2014-06-02 03:13:42 |
>   +-----------+---------------------+
>   11 rows in set (0.00 sec)

I need to gather statistics of how the groups are logging in the system, and I managed this so far :-

```
SELECT user_name,  group_type, COUNT(*) as number_of_logins
FROM logins.logins, users.user_groups 
WHERE username = user_name and group_type = 'group_2' 
GROUP BY user_name 
ORDER BY group_type, user_name;
```

which gives me

> +-----------+------------+------------------+
>   | user_name | group_type | number_of_logins |
>   +-----------+------------+------------------+
>   | user_4    | group_2    |                1 |
>   | user_5    | group_2    |                1 |
>   +-----------+------------+------------------+
>   2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

But I also need it to tell me user_6 has 0 number of logins like this :-

> +-----------+------------+------------------+
>   | user_name | group_type | number_of_logins |
>   +-----------+------------+------------------+
>   | user_4    | group_2    |                1 |
>   | user_5    | group_2    |                1 |
>   **| user_6    | group_2    |                0 |**
>
>   +-----------+------------+------------------+

I would be grateful if anyone would point me in the right direction

I have managed a solution via php using for / next loops, but I believe it would be faster via straight sql

Thanks in advance, and apologies for the lengthy question

J

Comment: I am sorry I was re-editing the whole thing, coz it looked like a mess, so I was adding "br" html tags to the tables. Must have deleted the edits by mistake than. Sorry My first post here

Comment: Possible duplicate? "How to include NULL values in a query with Outer Join and Group By" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8662833/how-to-include-null-values-in-a-query-with-outer-join-and-group-by

Answer (score 1):

Try using `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` like (`ug` and `ul` are table alias)

```
SELECT ug.user_name,  
ug.group_type, 
COUNT(ul.user_name) as number_of_logins
FROM users.user_groups ug
LEFT JOIN logins.logins ul ON ug.username = ul.user_name 
and ug.group_type = 'group_2' 
GROUP BY ul.user_name 
ORDER BY ug.group_type, ug.user_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you are joining will give you null values which won't be counted by the count() function.

Can you try doing a Left Join between the two tables using the username column?

```
SELECT user_name,  group_type, COUNT(*) as number_of_logins
FROM logins.logins LEFT JOIN users.user_groups ON logins.logins.user_name = users.user_groups.username 
WHERE username = user_name and group_type = 'group_2' 
GROUP BY user_name 
ORDER BY group_type, user_name;
```